# POST data has wrong value for Django template variable?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have the following code in my template:

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}  
    {%for category, category_votes in votes%}  
        <p>{{category}}: {{category_votes}} <!-- displays as expected -->  
            <input type="hidden" name="votedCat" value="{{category}}" id={{forloop.counter}}>  
            <input type="submit" name="upvote" value="Vote for...">  
            <input type="submit" name="downvote" value="Vote against...">  
        </p>  
    {%endfor%}  
</form>
```

The variable `{{category}}` displays as expected when rendered, but looking in the POST data, `"votedCat"` is always the last `category` value in `votes`.

For example, if `votes=[('a',1),('b',2),('c',3)]`, then `request.POST['votedCat']` returns `'c'` regardless of which input button is used to submit the form. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you only have one single form, with multiple inputs for `votedCat`. Clicking *any* of the buttons submits the whole form, with *all* the values for `votedCat`. If you were to access `request.POST.getlist('votedCat')` you would see that you actually have all the values.

There are two ways of fixing this. The first is to have separate form elements for each iteration through the loop - to do that, just move the `<form>` and `</form>` elements inside the loop.

The second is to have the `votedCat` input actually be the submit button:

```
<input type="submit" name="votedCat" value="Vote for {{category}}" id={{forloop.counter}}>
```

The disadvantage here is that now you have the words 'Vote for' in your variable, which you'll need to parse out in the view code.

Better than both of these would be to have a simple radio button set or select box with a single submit button, but I understand that design requirements sometimes get in the way.

Finally, you should really be using Django's forms framework, rather than using manual HTML and dealing with the POST directly.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I'll put the form inside the loop. Didn't know about .getlist() method, either. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the best solution, but you can create a new `form` inside the loop:

```
{%for category, category_votes in votes%}  
    <p>{{category}}: {{category_votes}} <!-- displays as expected -->  
    <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}  
        <input type="hidden" name="votedCat" value="{{category}}" id={{forloop.counter}}>  
        <input type="submit" name="upvote" value="Vote for...">  
        <input type="submit" name="downvote" value="Vote against...">
    </form>
    </p>  
{%endfor%}
```

You could consider using the [`django.forms.Form`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/) class to build and process your forms.